# Assign 0365 licensing to a list of users

Tags: powershell, office365, licensing

Trying to get a script to assign O365 license to a list of users. What am I missing here? I get the list of users to work, made based on SamAccountName length and the date the user is created. How can I get it to look at each of the users inside that list and assign it an O365 license if it is false? Is an IF statement ideal to use here?

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$date = (Get-Date).ToString()
$month = (Get-Date).AddDays(-4)

$NewUser = Get-ADuser -Filter * -Properties * | Where { ($_.samaccountname.length -eq 3 -and $_.whencreated -ge $month) } | Select-Object SamAccountName, UserPrincipalName, whencreated

Import-Module MSOnline
Connect-Module -Cred $User
foreach ($item in $NewUser) {Get-MsolUser -UserprincipalName $NewUser | where {$_.isLicensed -eq $false}
Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $NewUser.UserPrincipalName -AddLicenses $NewUser.licensetype
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use if statement is right. Please refer to the following:

```
foreach($user in $NewUser){

$AccountInfo = Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $user.UserPrincipalName -ErrorAction Stop

$CurrentAccountSku = $AccountInfo.Licenses.AccountSkuId


if($CurrentAccountSku -ne $null)
{
Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $user.UserPrincipalName    -AddLicenses 'contoso:ENTERPRISEPACK' -ErrorAction Stop
}

}
```

Here's a blog for adding different Skus to Office 365 user accounts.
http://blogs.technet.com/b/treycarlee/archive/2013/11/01/list-of-powershell-licensing-sku-s-for-office-365.aspx

Comment: Thanks a bunch! this made it clear. Just so I understand what's fully happening with the syntax.....what exactly is the syntax doing on the right side of the = sign for $CurrentAccountSku = $AccountInfo.Licenses.AccountSkuId? Is it saying, for each instance in $AccountInfo, look at the AccountSkuid object for each one? all this gets stored in the $CurrentAccountSku so that part I get.

Comment: **foreach($user in $NewADUsers) {
    if ($user.isLicensed -eq $False){ 
        Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $user.UserPrincipalName    -AddLicenses....et
    }
}**                                                                                                                             would this be a valid statement?

Comment: sorry for response late. The $user in $NewADUsers is the AD user object, which should have no attribute about license. You can change my script like this: foreach($user in $NewADUsers){$user = Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $user.UserPrincipalName -ErrorAction Stop; if($user.isLicensed -eq $false){Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $user.UserPrincipalName    -AddLicenses 'contoso:ENTERPRISEPACK' }}. The value for $user.License.AccountSkuId is equal to 'contoso:ENTERPRISEPACK' here.